# ros-fuerte-arm-navigation installation failure

Tags: ros-fuerte, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to install the ros-fuerte-arm-navigation package on a fresh install of ROS. I am getting the following errors when I run: sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-arm-navigation --fix-missing

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ros-fuerte-ompl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-fuerte-arm-navigation ros-fuerte-ompl
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 69.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 236 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ oneiric/main ros-fuerte-ompl amd64 0.11.0001998-0oneiric-20120702-2033-+0000
  404  Not Found
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ oneiric/main ros-fuerte-arm-navigation amd64 1.1.11-s1341612107~oneiric
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-ompl/ros-fuerte-ompl_0.11.0001998-0oneiric-20120702-2033-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation_1.1.11-s1341612107~oneiric_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Aborting install.
```

I have seen similar posts to this, but they seem to imply that there are left over packages from a previous install. Mine is a fresh install, so this is not the issue. Help would be much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39194/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation-installation-failure/) by [Steveb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2079/steveb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem seems to be solved. I tried the exact same command this afternoon and it worked (it did not work this morning or last night...). Not sure what happened here.

---

Originally posted by [Steveb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2079/steveb/) with karma: 26 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0